# React single page scroll to anchor without router or navigation uri

Tags: reactjs

I am curious about content structure for setting up this all too simple page.  There is a navigation/menu bar with links to an anchor referencing content further down the page.  I do not need react-router based hashing of the URL or history tracking. 
I don't want to have DOM queries within the navbar, but the issue I see is that my current setup has these components as siblings, so creating `ref`'s to the components means I have to create a janky middle handler to pass them between 2 places.

**Main App**

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <div className="app">
        <Navibar />
        <Jumbo />
        <About /> // should have a ref
        <Projects />  // should have a ref
        <Contact />  // should have a ref
      </div>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

**Navibar details**

```
handleClick = (e) => {
  window.scrollTo({
            top:this.myRef.current.offsetTop, 
            behavior: "smooth"
        })
}

<NavLink href="#about" onClick={this.handleClick}>About</NavLink>
```

At the main App level, I shouldn't need to make it a Class with props/state, it should just be a functional component.  Maybe this is where my logic is flawed?  However, if I made the App component to accept refCallbacks and pass them to Navibar, would that solve it?

Comment: I have two variations on this. One uses a div and the other a regular anchor tag. If you want a demo, I can provide some links

Comment: hi @Chimera.Zen yes, that would be great.  I am certainly curious.

Comment: [www.zenchiapps.com](http://www.zenchiapps.com) is a work in progress, but pretty much every link, whether a menu item or on page will do what you want. Let me know which one suits your needs and I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: the "program" and "about" submenu on your home page is the correct effect.  In reviewing your code on the site, it looks like your `handleScrollTo` method uses a DOM query which I was hoping to avoid.  I know it's a lightweight site, but I feel like the "react" way is to pass a ref instead...that is what I am hoping to find out.

Comment: Ok no problem. I'll modify my answer to use a ref that's passed to the function instead.

Comment: Is the below answer correct? If so, please mark it as such so it gets easier for other users to identify good solutions.

Answer (score 5):

The function in the `<li>` onClick helps prevent `handleScrollTo()` from firing on load

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  refA = React.createRef()
  refB = React.createRef()
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ loaded: true })
  }
  
  handleScrollTo = (elRef) => {
    // Incase the ref supplied isn't ref.current
    const el = elRef.current ? elRef.current : elRef
    
    // Scroll the element into view
    el.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth',
      block: 'start'
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <article>
        <header>
          <h1>ScrollTo Component</h1>
        </header>

        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li onClick={() => { this.handleScrollTo(this.refA) }}>
              Programs
            </li>
            <li onClick={() => { this.handleScrollTo(this.refB) }}>
              About
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        <div className="spacer"></div>

        <div ref={this.refA}>
          <h2>Programs</h2>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>

        <div className="spacer"></div>

        <div ref={this.refB}>
          <h2>About</h2>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
      </article>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.spacer {
  margin: 100px 0 100px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: ok, so you did make APP a component with class constructor and the ability to use Ref that can be passed between components.  That was my thought too.  THANKS

Comment: No problem. I'm happy to help :). If the solution works for you, can you please accept it so others that come here know that it worked? Thanks and best of luck in your future endeavors!

Comment: Could you give your reason for un-accepting this answer? It's important for people to know where it failed.

Comment: i didn't touch the answer that was accepted...not sure what it was before...